# Smaller sized banner with adMob

Tags: android, admob, android-dialog

Im new to AdMob, and am trying to add an ad in a Dialog. When i try and load it, it says there is not enough space to load the ad (480 requested, 420 available). On AdMob's site, it says i cannot display an add when theres not enough space, but on another page (http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html) it says banners are 320 pixels in width, NOT 480. Is there a way to load this smaller, 320px resolution banner?

Answer (score 0):

If you're requesting an ad in an activity, then the size is the second parameter of the AdView call--usually the constant AdSize.Banner, which gives the regular 320x50 phone ads:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);
```

If you're requesting an ad via the XML layout, then the ads:adSize determines the sizing (using the same contants).

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Might be able to offer more help if you have a code segment where you're requesting your ad and the layout of your dialog box.